# Spring Boot 1.5.8 server.port:0 already in use

Tags: spring-boot

Environment: Mac OSX 10.13  IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5

I have set server.port=0 within the application properties.  The problem is Java keeps trying ports that are already in use.

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 51939; nested exception is: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How to make sure Java does not select a used port?

Comment: Change the port of your java program, or kill the process that running on that port, run java java program, and run the process in different port.

Comment: server.port= 0 is supposed to select any available port.  No port to change and should not have to kill anything

Comment: `server.port` controls the HTTP port but the exception looks like it’s something to do with RMI. I’m not sure what is using port 51939, but I think that’s why `server.port` is having no effect

Comment: Oddly enough the problem vanished.  Changed nothing to make it work.  server.port is still set to `0`

Comment: Another note: the port error changed on every attempt. 59139 then 591xx, 592xx random ports each time.